# SQL Join IN Query with AND?

Tags: sql, relational-division

I have the following tables:

```
Option
-------
id - int
name - varchar

Product
---------
id - int
name -varchar

ProductOptions
------------------
id - int
product_id - int
option_id - int
```

If I have a list of option ids, how can I retrieve all Products that have all the options with the list of ids that I have? I know that SQL "IN" will use an "OR" i need an "AND". Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ids are not repeated, you can retrieve the ids of the options you need and count how many they are. Then, you just

```
SELECT product_id FROM ProductOptions
    WHERE option_id IN ( OPTIONS )
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(product_id) = NEEDED;
```

Without the GROUP BY, if you had five option ids, and product 27 had fifteen options among which there were those five, you'd get five rows with the same product_id. The GROUP BY joins those rows. Since you want ALL options, and options have all different IDs, asking "rows with all of them" is equivalent to asking "rows with as many options as the desired option set size".

Plus, you run the big query on ProductOptions only, which should be really fast.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach queries like this is with a group by and having clause.  It is best if you start with your list of required options in a list:

```
with list as (
    select <optionname1> as optionname union all
    select <optionname2 union all . . .
   )
select ProductId
from list l left outer join
     Options o
     on l.optionname = o.name
     ProductOptions po join
     on po.option_id = o.option_id left outer join
group by ProductId
having count(distinct o.optionname) = count(distinct l.optionname)
```

This guarantees that all are in the list.  By the way, I used SQL Server syntax to generate the list.

If you have the list in other formats, such as a delimited string, there are other options.  There are other possibilities depending on the database you are using.  However, the above idea should work on any database, with two caveats:

- The with statement might just become a subquery in the FROM clause where "list" is.
- The method for creating the list (a table of constants) varies among databases

Answer (score 1):

If you have list of Id's you have basically only 2 options.
- Either to call as many selects as many id's you have
- or you have to use IN () or OR.

The usage of IN would be recommended however, as calling one statement is usually more performant (moreover in case you have index on all your id columns, no table scan should be required).

I'd use following statement:

```
select Product.* from Product, Option, ProductOption where Option.id IN ( 1, 2, ... ) and option.id = ProductOption.option_id and Product.product_id = Product.id
```

One more remark, why do you have id column in ProductOptions table? It's useless from my point of view, you should rather have composite primary key from columns product_id and option_id (as this couple is unique).

Comment: ok, after reading your question again, I missed the point of all the options there => this won't work of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?:

```
select p.id, p.name 
from Product as p inner join
 ProductOptions as po on p.id=po.product_id 
where po.option_id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: nope..this will return products that have either option 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 but not all